# Swift 3: Nested Generic Type

Tags: swift, generics, types

I've got some weird behavior from the compiler I can't figure out (Xcode 8, Swift 3) as I'm trying to migrate my code from Swift 2.  I think it has to do with tuples, but I'm not entirely certain.

I've got a generic class that defines a couple generics.  In those generics, I've also got a couple type alias's setup and a function that uses them:

```
open class GuardPool <Key: Hashable, Resource> {

  public typealias ResourceCallback = ([Resource]) -> Void
  public typealias Request = (keys: Set<Key>, cb: ResourceCallback)
  fileprivate var pendingRequests: [Request] = []

  open func request(_ keys: Set<Key>, cb: ([Resource]) -> Void) {
    let pendingRequest: Request = (keys: keys, cb: cb)
    pendingRequests.append(pendingRequest)
  }
}
```

On the assignment (`let pendingRequest: Request = ...`), I get this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Set<Key>' to specified type 'Set<_>'
```

I cannot figure out how to fix this.  It seems like the compiler can't recognize the type information for `Set`.

*Note:* Obviously, the class is much larger that this.  I copied and pasted out the relevant code instead of inserting 300 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is misleading. If you remove 
the (unnecessary) explicit type annotation in the second line

```
    let pendingRequest = (keys: keys, cb: cb)
```

then the compiler states that

```
error: non-escaping parameter 'cb' may only be called
note: parameter 'cb' is implicitly non-escaping
```

which reveals the actual problem: The `cb` parameter must be marked as `@escaping` because
it is stored in a property and might be called at a later time,
after returning from the `request` method:

```
open func request(_ keys: Set<Key>, cb: @escaping ([Resource]) -> Void) {
    let pendingRequest = (keys: keys, cb: cb)
    pendingRequests.append(pendingRequest)
}
```

In Swift 2, closures were escaping by default and could be marked
with `@noescape`. In Swift 3, closures are non-escaping by default,
compare [SE-0103: Make non-escaping closures the default](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0103-make-noescape-default.md).

Comment: Yep... that was a very misleading error message.  I just figured that out and was going to answer my own question but you beat me to it!  Thanks!

Comment: With over 40k lines of code to work through, the migrator missed a bunch of places where a closure should be marked `@escaping`.  The explicit assignment was done because I originally got the error on this `pendingRequests.append((keys: keys, cb: cb))`.  I was hoping adding an explicitly typed assignment would fix the problem, but kept getting the same error.  Interestingly, this same error has occurred in a few places in my code where a nested type and closure were combined in a tuple.